# How to Change Workflow Variable List Columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, custom-list

I have a SharePoint List that has a Customer Number and a Customer Name Column,

When the approver gets the email it says in the Subject Line: Tasks - Please Approve "Customer Number" I would like Customer Number to be changed to "Customer Name"  How do I change these? in the workflow variable I see:

Data source: Current Task: "Name of Workflow"
Field from source:         "Task Name"

Task Name seems to be pulling Customer Number, how can I get to pull Customer Name instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by clicking on 3 points buttos and you'll be able to choice whitch column you want to display on Sabject

[image]